# JUnit5: create new file in build directory

Tags: java, gradle, testing, junit, junit5

I have a Spring Boot application that provides Open API specification by `/api/open-api/v3` path. The idea is that I request the Open API JSON during test running and then write its content to the file in `build` folder. So, I could parse it later and generate documentation. I tried to do it like this:

```java
Files.writeString(Path.of("src", "test", "resources", "open-api.json"), res.getBody());
```

It did write the the file to the `src/test/resources` folder but in the source code module itself. Not the result `build` folder. Is it possible to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Create a file on the build diretory")
void createFileOnBuildDir() throws IOException {

    final URL buildRoot = getClass().getResource("/");
    final Path jsonFile = Path.of(buildRoot.getPath(), "open-api.json");
    Files.writeString(jsonFile, "{\"value\": 123}");
    System.out.println(jsonFile);
}
```

result

```
/home/myuser/projects/testproject/build/classes/java/test/open-api.json
```

```
$ cat /home/myuser/projects/testproject/build/classes/java/test/open-api.json
{"value": 123}
```

But, I guess the best answer for your need is https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/spring-swagger2markup-demo project's https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/spring-swagger2markup-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/robwin/swagger2markup/petstore/Swagger2MarkupTest.java

Comment: Thanks, that did work. I heard about Spring REST Docs but I've never tried. I'll look this through